# Why is this query returning only the first 11 rows only?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * 
from projects
where projects.project_code in (select distinct_code from only_project_code where distinct_code is not null)
```

There are 84 matching values between distinct_code and project_code. But this query is returning only 11. Why?

Tables are here. Notice the query run on them.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Without your data we cannot tell for sure. Your query is supposed to return the projects whichs project codes are IN the result of your subquery. My wager is your subquery has some results that you expect to match your project codes but don't. Maybe due to trailing spaces or something similar.

Comment: This query returns rows from the table `projects`. Are there 84 rows in `projects` with `project_code` that exists in `only_project_code`?

Comment: @VineetBasantani . . . You *think* the values are matching, but there are hidden characters or some other issue that causes them not to match.

Comment: If there were hidden characters, they would be in all of them. How come 11 rows are matching?

Comment: For the small amount of data you have why not publish it to sqlfiddle or dbfiddle so we can get our hands on it.

Comment: *There are 84 matching values between distinct_code and project_code. But this query is returning only 11.* 84 records of `projects.project_code` which matches at least one record in `distinct_code` each?

Comment: Execute `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT projects.project_code, only_project_code.distinct_code) FROM projects, only_project_code WHERE projects.project_code = only_project_code.distinct_code;` and the same with one field (for each field) in COUNT- what are the results?

Answer (score 2):

That because of table `projects` may contains unique values, if you want duplicate you need a *JOIN* :

```
select p.project_code, pc.distinct_code 
from projects p inner join -- you may need LEFT JOIN instead 
     only_project_code pc
     on pc.distinct_code = p.project_code;
```

Comment: @VineetBasantani. . . Try to add `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Left join beats the whole point because I only need matching values. Though I tried it and it gave me the original 1416 values, that are the total values in distinct_code

Comment: @VineetBasantani Try this code with a RIGHT JOIN and to see which of your distinct_code results has no match in the project code table.